# Strange MXM SLi card behavior

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, sli

I have a [2008 Dell XPS M1730](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/xps-m1730/docs) laptop that I have recently acquired a brand new still in plastic dual 0K650M 9800M GTX card for, but I haven’t been able to get the SLi to work correctly.

When viewing the card from the laptop’s BIOS, every time it should appear as a 2048MB 9800 GTX, due to the fact that it’s a dual card, but ever since I’ve received the card, it’s always appeared as a 1GB card, until you do exactly this…

1. Enter BIOS and switch Fast Boot to ‘Thorough’
2. Exit BIOS and allow ‘Thorough’ boot to complete.
3. Allow the laptop to boot into Windows.
4. Shutdown (Not restart) Windows.
5. Turn laptop on again and allow ‘Thorough’ boot to complete again.
6. Finally, allow laptop to boot into Windows once again.

After completing this process, the second card is visible in Device Manager, SLi becomes available in NVIDIA Control Panel, and the BIOS shows the card as 2GB. But, if you turn off the laptop for about 10-15 minutes, the second card disappears from everything, and the BIOS shows it as 1GB. Repeating the above process brings the second card back.

Removing the CMOS has no affect on this, neither did replacing the thermal paste, flashing the VBIOS for both cards, trying different power supplies and batteries, trying the card in another M1730 laptop, removing the dedicated  Ageia PhysX card, different NVIDIA drivers, nothing I’ve tried has changed this strange behavior, **which should not happen.**

I’m running the A11 update of the motherboard’s BIOS, but I’ve seen others with the same version using this card without this issue.

With SLi enabled, usually only the Windows UI can be rendered without the laptop completely freezing, but for some reason, if PhysX is not installed as part of the drivers, and if you have the PhysX dedication set to CPU, one of my games can be played, a simple 2D arcade game running on DirectX 9 that has some basic 3D graphics and runs at a resolution of 800 x 600. No other games can be played without freezing, not even Minesweeper of all things or Windows’ default screensavers.

I’ve used a [VRAM testing tool](https://m.majorgeeks.com/files/details/video_memory_stress_test.html) to see if this may be the problem, but it turned up nothing.

I have observed a few rare instances of a BSoD displaying the following…

```
*** Hardware Malfunction
Call your hardware vendor for support
NMI: Parity check / Memory Parity Error
*** The system has halted ***
```

I also once observed an RSoD, the entire screen turned completely red and displayed nothing else. This happened only one time.

Edit: I ran a couple tests where I intentionally tried to trigger the system to freeze with SLi on and running something, with GPU-Z logging to a file, and at the very end of the log just as the system freezes, it shows the voltage for the second chip drop to 0.0 but all other values stay the same. This only happens for the second chip though.

Edit 2: I decided to take apart the card again, and I checked the etching on each chips’ die.

Both graphics chips have the same info etched on the die;

```
NVIDIA
UA08B019 1032A2
S TAIWAN
  NN3767.M4R
    
   G92-740-A2
```

From the numbers I believe to be the date codes, it looks like these chips were produced on the 32nd week of 2010. The G92-740 number also verifies that these are in fact, 9800 chips, so no problems there.

I also looked at the SLi bridge/PCI-E switch chip, and found something odd.

```
NVIDIA     0629A3
NA2700.00B A  TAIWAN
     BR03-N-A3
```

At first I thought it read the 29th week of 2008, but with a magnifying glass, I realized it reads the 29th week of 2006.
This does not appear to be the right version for this card. Here’s an [image](https://www.4gamer.net/review/7950gx2/img/07.jpg) of a BR03 chip produced around the same time, and the [article](https://www.4gamer.net/review/7950gx2/7950gx2.shtml) I found it on.

I’ve been able to find a working example of a 9800M GTX SLi [here](https://www.retropcmania.com/2012/07/dell-xps-m1730-with-dual-9800m-gtx.html?m=1), and an [image](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-oMIfKtd4gaw/UA57Kk6u-3I/AAAAAAAAMrA/kE_eHa26DX4/s1600/_1060992.JPG) of the board from that blog post.

The graphics chips on this card were produced on the 24th week of 2010, so about the same time mine were manufactured.

Because of the resolution of the image, the SLi bridge date code is not discernible. But, if you look closely at the chip’s die, though it’s difficult to see, the styling of the NVIDIA logo is a different updated version from the logo design on my SLi bridge chip, the N in NVIDIA is a dead giveaway. This is how I’m able to tell that on this working 9800, the SLi bridge chip is a newer version, probably produced around 2007-2008, which is when they started using this updated logo. Here’s an [image](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/pAsAAOSwxSZbwhhp/s-l500.jpg) of a late-2007 BR03.

I haven’t been able to find any 9800s for the M1730 online with a 2006 BR03 SLi bridge, which makes me think that mine was a manufacturer mistake. The wrong SLi bridge must’ve been soldered on, and that must be why the SLi has never worked correctly. The odd behavior with Thorough Boot bringing the second graphics chip back temporarily, and the fact it crashes with SLi enabled when running the simplest things, must be the fault of this outdated chip.

I guess the solution must be to replace the chip? There are some newer BR03 chips on eBay for cheap, and I think I can find a repair specialist who can solder the new one on. The problem is I don’t know for sure if the chip I buy will be compatible, and I haven’t been able to find a data sheet on it.

Comment: Note that the NVIDIA GeForce 9800M GTX "does not require any additional power connector, its power draw is rated at 75 W maximum. " https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-9800m-gtx.c941 Can the laptop handle that? Perhaps it needs a new battery to handle *peak* power.

Comment: The power supply is rated ~240w and while the battery is certainly not new, it should be able to handle it, as I have used an 8800M GTX SLi before with no power issues.

Comment: Also even if power is the issue, shouldn’t I be able to atleast see the NVIDIA 3D test logo with the SLi on? That shouldn’t require the cards to run at their max wattage.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the ISO (with something like PowerISO or whatever), is there a .ROM file in there? Do you have the Nvflash software? Also, check out https://archive.org/search?query=XPS+M1730 Looks like everything you need is in there

Comment: The ISO seems to be in a strange format, iso9660 I believe, and when opened with 7zip, all that’s in there is a folder called [BOOT] inside of which is another ISO and then finally a file called fat.

Comment: Well I burned the ISO using cdburnxp, and this time it actually worked, a FreeDOS based utility popped up with a continue prompt. Unfortunately, for some reason, it was not able to read the roms on the disc, and therefore did not update. Perhaps I need to use a CD and maybe change some burn settings? I guess this is some really old technology, maybe even for 2008 standards.

Comment: @HyperBlend Use https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/?architecture=NVIDIA&manufacturer=&model=&version=&interface=&memType=&memSize=&since=

Comment: Tried that already, could only find one of the two roms https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/153588/153588

Comment: What was the FreeDOS error message, if any?

Comment: I/O ERROR: Cannot open file: 92gtxsli0.rom I/O ERROR: Cannot open file: 92gtxsli1.rom

Comment: There are ROM files in the Archive.org link i posted tho I386\R154164\OROM\ROBSON\PROD.ROM
I386\R166201\OROM\ROBSON\PROD.ROM
X64\R154164\OROM\ROBSON\PROD.ROM
X64\R166201\OROM\ROBSON\PROD.ROM
X64\R191846\OROM\ROBSON\PROD.ROM

Comment: Upon opening with a text editor, these all appear to be Intel roms, probably for motherboards. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: ETA on that other ISO is 9 min. Bit weird that you can find https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/61697/61697 and 
https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/69980/69980 Long shot, but you could try emailing support

Comment: https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/nvidia-bios-editor-download-nibitor.html NiBiTor (NVIDIA BIOS Editor) seems to support it

Comment: Perhaps I can use FreeDOS to navigate the disc and manually extract the roms, since there doesn’t seem to be an established way to do this on Windows. I’ll try this in a VM. I’ll have to check out that other ISO on archive.org as well.

Comment: There are a bunch of roms in that other archive.org link as well. I'll seed it ;-)